# Angular 2 observable sub-objects

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm looking for help with my understanding of Observables/Subjects in Angular2. I have an app where I am trying to display some data of the following format:

```
sections = [
    {
        _id: '999'
        name: 'section 1'
        items: [
            {
                name: "item 1.1"
                property1: "value 1.1.1"
                property2: "value 1.1.2"
                property3: "value 1.1.3"
            }
            {
                name: "item 1.2"
                property1: "value 1.2.1"
                property2: "value 1.2.2"
                property3: "value 1.2.3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: '888'
        name: 'section 2'
        items: [
            {
                name: "item 2.1"
                property1: "value 2.1.1"
                property2: "value 2.1.2"
                property3: "value 2.1.3"
            }
            {
                name: "item 2.2"
                property1: "value 2.2.1"
                property2: "value 2.2.2"
                property3: "value 2.2.3"
            }
        ]
    }
    .
    .
    .
]
```

To do this, I have set up a component tree that looks like this:

```
'data view component'
    |
     --> 'section component'
        |
         --> 'data item component'
```

Where 'data view component' holds the list of sections as an observable called sectionData$, which is passed into the section component like so:

```
<section-component
    *ngFor="let section of sectionData$ | async"
></section-component>
```

The 'section-component' hosts the 'data item component' and data is passed in like so:

```
 <data-item-component
    *ngFor="let item of section.items"
></data-item-component>
```

when a change occurs, i.e. sectionData$.next() is called... the entire component tree is updated, even though the change may only occur on one or two of the items within a given section. This can be quite slow, depending on the complexity and size of the data to be rendered on screen

How can I make my components update only when their respective subobjects of the parent observable changes?

Answer (score 1):

This is where customTrackBy function kicks in. If you can be sure that your section's ID is unique, tell Angular to track the item by its ID:

```
<section-component *ngFor="let section of sectionData$ | async;trackBy:customTrackBy"></section-component>
```

And inside your `data view component`, add the customTrackBy function:

```
customTrackBy(index, sec) {
    return sec._id;
}
```

Same idea can be applied to items too.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/mG2kYiInXIYsrmRqgajS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage the Componenet Meta Data property "changeDetection". This will cause Angular 2 to skip sending a change out of the component if nothing changed. Since you are using an Observable you will also need to leverage ChangeDetectorRef object, so you can tell Angular 2 something has changed in the component when it receives data from the subcribe method. More details can be found [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html).

Comment: the change detection looks promising.. but if I have one observable that contains data for many components, and next() is called... even if only one part of the data is changed, won't angular treat this as a new data object, and therefore all components who depend on it will need to change?

Comment: @AdrianTaylor: In my experience and based on the documentation, no. When you use subscribe on observables and your changeDetection is set to "OnPush", you have to tell Angular2 when a change has occurred. This means you can evaluate and decide if a change has occurred and then alert Angular2 to it using the ChangeDetecorRef object.